# Redis get data using python

Tags: python, redis

I have done the following to get json file data into redis using this python script-

```
import json
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=1)
with open('products.json') as data_file:
    test_data = json.load(data_file)
r.set('test_json', test_data)
```

When I use the **get** commmand from redis-cli (get test_json) I get **nil** back.
I must be using the wrong command?
Please help for my understanding on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hmset` instead of set and `hgetall` instead of get to store multiple keys, your code should look like:

```
r.hmset('test_json', test_data) #to set multiple index data
r.hgetall('test_json') #to get multiple index data
```

Comment: I think you are right that I should be using the redis hash to load in my values, but I suspect I am loading in my json file ([link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BestBuyAPIs/open-data-set/master/products.json)) wrong?
How can I take advantage of being able to recall all of the values under the "name" key

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the previous answer. Didn't noticed the problem there is that u specified 'db=1' in the redis constructor. So you are saving the data in the db 1. type 'select 1' in the redis client, or remove that from the constructor (by default, with redis-cli you connect to database 0)

Comment: That is helpful. BTW I am new to redis completely (obviously). Just trying to get my json key values in there to start. 
My json file: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BestBuyAPIs/open-data-set/master/products.json).
There are multiple key value columns. Ultimately I want to search the "name" by value. Trying to build an autocomplete in an html page. Using redis as the DB.